# Why am I forbidden from accessing this website from my home internet connection, but can access it from my cell phone?

Tags: website

If I try to visit a gmx.com from my desktop computer, I get the message:

> Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /portal-2.36.0.0/ on
>   this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But the site opens without a problem on my cell phone internet connection. I've never visited this site before on either device. Why is it blocked on my home internet connection ?

EDIT: gmx.net opens without a problem. Its the same company though.

EDIT: mail.com which is owned by the same company also works without a problem.

Comment: Hi John, few questions: Which service provider are you using? Are you using Wi-Fi? Have you tried to access it from someone else's computer?

Comment: As I said - i can access the website from my cellphone, but not from my home internet connection. It is wifi - but that isn't the problem. I would get the same message if I used ethernet. Both services are provided by the same company.

Comment: Are you entering the URL directly into your browser you going via a search engine?

Comment: Your cell phone is using a different route to the website.  It sounds like this is a configuration problem on the part of the website itself.

Comment: Have you tried: 1) changing your DNS server via router settings or local PC settings?  If you're on the default ISP's settings, try 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 1.1.1.1, etc.  2) Checking if you're blacklisted on your ISP-provided connection (e.g., online tools like [this one](https://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check)).  3) Isolated and confirmed the issue is exclusive to connection (e.g., will it load for PC if you tether via your mobile data connection?).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone who had your IP address before you got blocked for spamming or attacking them.

Or it happened a lot from your home ISP, so they blocked an entire section of the network block used by your ISP.

Really though, this is just conjecture, probably only the site owners can tell you why you're blocked, and they might not even know off-hand if, say, they're using auto-blocking, or blacklist protection systems of some kind.

Before you go ripping out networking, reformatting and such, you should [contact 1&1](http://www.gmx.com/about.html) (the owners) and ask them what's going on.