# ISP blocked by website

Tags: website

The title is not a typo. When I am trying to access transfermarkt.com transfermarkt.co.uk and transfermarkt.de from my home network on any unit (PC, mobile, etc.) it gives me a page saying "403 forbidden nginx". If I try to use mobile data instead or connect to a different wifi it works fine.

I think transfermarkt blocked me because I have been scraping their site, so it probably detected that a lot of traffic was coming from an ISP over a couple of days and then somehow blocked it (I wasn't blocked instantly it was a couple of days after). Maybe they have blacklisted some kind of ID of my router or ISP, is there some way to renew that, like renewing an IP address on a PC so I won't be blacklisted anymore?

The only similar question I was able to find was this:

[Why am I forbidden from accessing this website from my home internet connection, but can access it from my cell phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/715929/why-am-i-forbidden-from-accessing-this-website-from-my-home-internet-connection)

And there wasn't really any answers I could use, I seriously doubt I could convince transfermarkt to unblock me.

Forgive me if I sound ignorant, my question is just if there is a way to bypass the ban?

Comment: They most likely just blocked your external IP.

Comment: The IP address of my PC isn't blocked. I can access the website just fine if I connect to another network. If I try to use any device even my phone on my home network it doesn't work.

Comment: @JakeGould I was just pointing it out to SonicKyle27 when typing ipconfig the external IP (IPv4) is a public IP that changes from unit to unit (that's what I meant by IP address of my PC). The local address is only visible inside the private network (IPv6) and the IP address of the modem/router is the one that is blocked (Default Gateway), correct?

Comment: The router will have 2 IP's, one internal (which you see as your gateway on your machine), and one external (which is what's blocked).

Comment: "that's what I meant by IP address of my PC" - So describe it by the correct name.  An **intranet** ip address, by calling an ip address, a public ip address you describe something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external IP is blocked, fixes may include:

1. Rebooting your router - you may get a different public IP after a reboot.
2. Contacting your ISP to get a new IP - some ISP's will change your IP if you just request it.
3. Using a vpn or other tunnelling service to hide your external IP - many free tunnelling services exist, however be sure of the reputation of any service you use as they can see *all* your internet traffic.
4. Using tor
5. Using a mobile connection such as a mobile hotspot, or setting up internet sharing via a mobile phone
6. Using a web cafe.

Answer (score 1):

> **I have been scraping their site**

Did you get permission?

> The content of this website is protected by copyright. Reprint, inclusion in online services, Internet and duplication on data carriers such as CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, etc., may only be made in part, with the prior written consent of Transfermarkt. Commercial re-marketing of the content is prohibited.

(their legal notice)

> **My *IP* has been blocked ... Is there a way I can bypass this ban?**

Yes, both legal and not-legal.

You could explain to them why you need their data wholesale, what you intend to do with it, and get their permission.

Bypassing a ban based on IP-addresses is simply a matter of obtaining a different IP-address, this might be as simple as rebooting a router or switching ISP. By doing so you are likely in breach of the sites terms and conditions though.

Comment: According to whatismyipaddress.com I have a static IP address, so I don't think I can change my IP address by resetting my router. Why has no one mentioned the possibility of using VPN? I tested it and it worked. Too bad they all either cost money or put restrictions and give you malware and sell your private data.

Comment: Oh and no I haven't gotten their permission. I have never heard of anyone ever asking for permission before scraping a bit of data off a random site and I can't imagine they would allow it. I'm not overloading the servers, or scraping all data and reselling it or anything. I just need some data for a neural network (small private project), that's all.

Comment: Downvoted as it doesn't actually explain how to bypass a block in any meaningful way. I realise this maybe a moral quandary.

Comment: Scraping in itself is not illegal, many big corporations like Google does it big time. Bypassing a block is not illegal either to my knowledge, that's just the automated rules of the website. This is not idiosyncratic, I assume many different websites can block your router IP and there are multiple ways to bypass it. Downvotes are unjustified from my perspective.